# Create an object based on data from a text file

Tags: java, performance

The following method reads specially formatted text ([TOML](http://github.com/toml-lang/toml)) from a file and parses the input using a parser to get a few properties, which are then used to create an object.

The profiler tells me that this method is the bottleneck in my program. While parsing ~5000 files, this method eats up over 95% of the total running time. While in another method, I am able to write the data parsed from this method to a text file in under 4 seconds for more than 5000 files, this method takes around 15 seconds on an average to run.

```
/**
* Creates an appropriate instance of a Parsable implementation depending
* upon the header of the file.
*
* @param file the path of the file from which to create a Parsable.
* @return the created Parsable.
*/
private Parsable createParsable(Path file) {
    Toml toml = new Toml();
    try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        StringBuilder header = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && !line.equals(HEADER_DELIMITER)) {
        header.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        toml.parse(header.toString());
        String title = toml.getString("title");
        author = toml.getString("author") != null ? toml.getString("author") : author;
        String date = toml.getString("date");
        String slug = toml.getString("slug");
        LocalDate publishDate = LocalDate.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(config.getDateFormat()));
        String layout = toml.getString("layout");
        List<String> tag = toml.getList("tags");
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            content.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        if (layout.equals("post")) {
            return new Post(title, author, publishDate, file, content.toString(), slug, layout, tag);
        }
        else {
            return new Page(title, author, file, content.toString(), slug, layout, tag);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DirectoryCrawler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

It is important to note that this method gets called over 5000 times in my test.
I have tried analyzing separate parts of the method for the performance problem, but haven't been able to identify any. How can I write this better?

The TOML library is from here : https://github.com/mwanji/toml4j

And the implementation of the constructors are like so:

```
/**
 * Creates a Post with the given paramenter.
 *
 * @param titl the post title
 * @param auth the post author
 * @param dat the post date
 * @param loc the post's Path
 * @param cont the post's content
 * @param slu the post slug
 * @param lay the layout
 * @param tag the list of tags
 */
public Post(String titl, String auth, LocalDate dat,
            Path loc, String cont, String slu, String lay, List<String> tag) {
    title = titl;
    author = auth;
    //TODO add summary option
    //this.summary = summ;
    date = dat;
    location = loc;
    content = cont;
    slug = slu;
    layout = lay;
    tags = tag;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the implementation of `new Toml()`?

Comment: I also think sharing the implementations for your `Post` and `Page` constructors will be useful too, if they are non-trivial.

Comment: @h.j.k. I added the constructor. But I dont think that is the bottleneck as creation of objects is really cheap in Java. Plus, the profiler tells me that the Toml functions don't take too much time (around ~500ms at most).

Comment: what java version do you have available?

Comment: @Vogel612 Java 1.8.0_25

Comment: How much of the overhead is in `toml.parse(header.toString());`? How much in IO? (Try replacing each result with a cached value and seeing the timing difference.)

Comment: @Veedrac Not much. As I said, all the toml function calls combined take around half a second only.

Comment: @Pawan So what parts are taking the majority of the time?

Comment: @Veedrac The profiler shows it as "self time" for the createParsable method. Which I guess means the time spent apart from all the calls delegated to other methods. So time is being spend in the file I/o somewhere. My best guess is that opening and closing so many files is the culprit. Can't confirm though.

Comment: @Pawan Remove the IO (replace the file with a `List<String>`) and see how much faster it is.

Answer (score 2):

I see that the processing you're doing here does not depend on the order you're processing in. This means you can parallelize the processing heavily.

Additionally you're doing line-by-line processing, which allows you to use one of the new features of Java 8, namely [`Files.lines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-)

This greatly simplifies the code you have to following outline:

```
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path).parallel()) {
   // do line by line processing
} catch (IOException e) {
   // sensible handling
}
```

Also it might be faster to keep parsables in "one" file, this reduces channel and OS waiting overhead for Open/Close operations when doing I/O

Comment: Thanks for the Files.lines hint. It never crossed my mind to use Streams here. I'll try to parallelize the process. However, I can't keep parsables in one file, as they are separate files which will be created by the end user.

Comment: Doesn't the `while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && !line.equals(HEADER_DELIMITER))` block prevent easy parallelism?

Comment: @Veedrac that's just a simple `.filter()` IIUC... basically the br.readLine() happens inside the stream and you just have to filter out nulls and HEADERs

Comment: @Vogel612 It looks to me like a `takeWhile`, not a `filter`.